# Webpage not sized to viewport on load on mobile device

Tags: iphone, mobile, responsive-design, viewport

Can anyone tell me why this page wont resize the width to the viewport of an iPhone on load?

https://exposurebasketballtournaments.com/events/scheduletable/8331?layout=time&type=pool&output=html&download=false

I have

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: you might want to change it to  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

Comment: I want them to be able to scale.

Comment: why isn;t your initial scale 2.3?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you have the following style:

```
.document #wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 716px;
```

}

Remove that width setting and you are good to go!

Cheers

Comment: Then the width wont fit in my PDF correctly when it renders from the HTML.

Comment: Also I just tried it, and I cant even scroll right, not working.

Comment: You can view it here, https://demo.exposurebasketballtournaments.com/events/scheduletable/8331?layout=time&type=pool&output=html&download=false

Comment: I'm not clear what's not working for you. Here's what I see on my iPhone http://bit.ly/13ZzrgG . Everything fits on the screen so there's no reason to scroll right. The PDF is a different question. I don't understand exactly the problem you are describing, though customising the @ media settings would probably help. Here are some ideas to get you started: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/?p=106631  Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes sorry you are correct.  I kind of like that view, but would rather have the initial view show the entire length of the table, meaning 716px in width on the screen.  This condenses it which is OK, but wont work with other reports I have.  If you go to adidassuper64.com, the initial page view is the entire page.  I want the entire page to also be shown initially here too.

Comment: I'm not sure that you'll be able to reliably get the entire length and the full width of the table to always show. Long tables will likely be an issue. You could try playing with the initial-scale=1.0 value to see if you can get something close to what you want. Alternatively you could completely remove the viewpoint metatag and rely on the iPhone to scale the page as it sees fit.